# How do I convert this array into list in my specific case?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have iterated through an array `B`. Checked whether there are elements that are common in an arrayList `A`. Then removed those elements and printed out `A` as an array.

**But my question is how can I print out `A`(in my program it's `System.out.println(crIss.get(m));`) as an arrayList (Just a list of element without `[]` bracket) instead of an array?**

This is the complete code I am working on:

```
package issuetracking;

import java.util.*;

public class IssueTrackingObject {

    ArrayList<String> crIss = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean crIss_bool;
    int numOfSolvedIss;
    private String[] solvedIss;

    //lets user create some issues and add them into an arrayList
    public void createIssue() {
        System.out.println("Enter 5 issues: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Issue " + (i + 1 + ": "));
            crIss_bool = crIss.add(input.nextLine());
        }

    }
//Let user mark some issues as solved (which are already in the list that the user has just created)

    public void solvedIssue() {
        System.out.println("How many solved issue you have(Must be less than 5): ");
        numOfSolvedIss = input.nextInt();

        solvedIss = new String[numOfSolvedIss];

        for (int k = 0; k < numOfSolvedIss; k++) {
            System.out.print("Enter solved issue(REMEMBER THAT THE SOLVED ISSUE MUST BE FROM ONE OF THEM YOU ALREADY HAVE CREATED)no. " + (k + 1) + ": ");

            solvedIss[k] = input.next();
        }

    }

    public void printUnsolvedIssue() {

for(int m=0; m<solvedIss.length;m++){
      crIss_bool = crIss.remove(solvedIss);

    System.out.println(crIss.get(m));   
}


    }


    public void printSolvedIssue() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("LIST OF SOLVED ISSUE:");

        for (int l = 0; l < solvedIss.length; l++) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", solvedIss[l]);
        }

    }

}
```

main class:

```
package issuetracking;

import java.util.*;

public class IssueTracking {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IssueTrackingObject its = new IssueTrackingObject();

        System.out.println("                            WELCOME TO ISSUE TRACKING SYSTEM!\n\n");
        System.out.println("Choose from menu: ");
        System.out.println("1. Create new issue\n2. Mark issue(s) as solved\n"
                + "3. View solved issue(s)\n4. View unsolved issue(s)");
        System.out.println("Enter you choise:");
        //String userChoise = input.next();
        //switch-case

        while (true) {
            String userChoise = input.next();

            switch (userChoise) {
                case "1":
                    //System.out.println("Enter 5 issues: ");
                    //call appropriate issue
                    its.createIssue();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    //System.out.println("Mark solved issues (You must enter at least one issue): ");
                    //call appropriate issue
                    its.solvedIssue();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.out.println("Solved issue: ");
                    //call appropriate method
                    its.printSolvedIssue();
                    break;

                case "4":
                    System.out.println("Usolved issue: ");
                    //call appropriate issue
                    its.printUnsolvedIssue();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    break;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Do you want to create an `ArrayList` from the array? Or do you want to iterate the existing array and print out the elements?

Comment: Loop through it and print each item in the array on a new line.

Comment: Are you allowed to use additional libraries, such as Apache Commons?  If so, there's a nice method called `join` in the `StringUtils` class which will do the hard part for you.

Comment: Ascalonian, I agree. but my edited post has improved the situation I guess. Can u understand by looking at my code now? I just want to print out crIss as list.

Comment: `printUnsolvedIssue` looks wrong.  `m` is an index that iterates through `solvedIss`.  But then you use `m` as an index into `crIss`, after you remove an element from it.  The indexes in `crIss` will not match the indexes in `solvedIss`, so the result is that you will display the wrong elements.  You're going to need a second `for` loop.

Comment: @Riyana, you just edited the code completely.  A minute ago, it was using arrays everywhere - now it's using `ArrayList` in a few places.  Which is it supposed to be?  It's very hard to write a correct answer to a question that keeps changing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just iterate through `crIss` and print each item in it, followed by the desired delimiter. In this example, I will separate the items with ", ".

```
public void printUnsolvedIssue() {

   for(int m=0; m<solvedIss.length;m++){
       crIss.remove(solvedIss[i]);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < crIss.size(); i++) {
       System.out.print(crIss.get(i));
       // only print the delimiter if it isn't the last item in the list
       if(i < crIss.size() - 1) {
           System.out.print(", ");
       }
   }
}
```

Also notice I changed the `crIss.remove(solvedIss)` part to `crIss.remove(solvedIss[i])`. This way it will remove each item in `solvedIss`.

Comment: That's not a good way to iterate through the elements of a `List`. Use a proper iterator or an enhanced `for` loop instead.

Comment: By the way, this won't cover what OP wants/needs: *how can I print out A as an arrayList (Just a list of element without [] bracket) instead of an array?*

Comment: Translating this to you (and other readers): instead of printing `"[1, 2, 3]"`, OP needs to print `"1, 2, 3"`. Your code prints `"1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n`.

Comment: forgivenson, size() method doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Riyana I think you need to clarify your question more. You are trying to print out a list of the unsolved issues, correct?

Comment: yes, forgivenson. Thats what I want. I will also add my main class code in a second in my post so that you know.

Comment: @Riyana Please see my above comment.  You have a loop that iterates through `solvedIss` but uses the same index to get `crIss` elements, which is wrong; that may be why you think `size()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Riyana I updated my answer based on your clarifications

Comment: forgivenson, its awesome.  Thats what I wanted. A simple thanks would be too little, i know. Really, there r a lots of smart people I saw who try to contribute and help as much as they can. this is very welcoming a nice to me.

Answer (score 1):

The printing behavior you are exprienging is becasue when you print an object like an `ArrayList`, Java calls the Class's `.toString()` method.  `ArrayList.toString()` is inherited from `AbstractCollection.toString()` which documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()).

My suggestion to change this behavior is to create a sepreate Print function similar to the following:

```
public void printList(ArrayList<String> list)
{
     for(String str : list)
     {
          System.out.print(str+" ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Then call this function in place of your print statement:

```
printList(crIss);
```

Note that this print will print each element of your List on one line, separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I'll show you three:

1. Storing the data in a `String` and remove the unrequired characters:

   ```
   String tmp = crIss.toString();
   tmp = tmp.substring(1, tmp.length() - 1);
   System.out.println(tmp);
   ```
2. Similar to approach above but using `replace`:

   ```
   String tmp = crIss.toString().replace('[', '\0').replace(']', '\0');
   System.out.println(tmp);
   ```
3. Iterating through your `List` and storing the values in `StringBuilder`:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (String string : crIss) {
       sb.append(string).append(", ");
   }
   sb.remove(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
   ```